# Change number automatically with function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple function that get a number and sum + 1:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextProjectNumber] ()  
RETURNS INT
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LegacyKey INT

    SELECT @LegacyKey = (MAX(CAST(LegacyKey AS INT)) + 1) 
    FROM Project; 

    RETURN @LegacyKey;
END
```

So every year we change `@LegacyKey` number for new one manually like:

```
In 2017: 18000
In 2018: 19000
In 2019: 20000
etc..
```

This happen every 1st of October, so I want to know if its possible to change it automatically.

Today value should be `20000`, once I change it it should sum `+ 1` since October of `2020`, in October of 2020 it should change to `21000`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: So, let me understand correctly, rows that are inserted(?) should have the value `20000` for the value from October 2019 onwards. From October 2020 they should be `21000`?

Comment: Exactly, On Octuber of 2020 should be `21000` @Larnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative:

```
select (year(dateadd(month, 3, getDate())) - 2000) * 1000
```

Example 1:

```
select (year(dateadd(month, 3, '2019-09-30 13:29:07.433')) - 2000) * 1000
```

Returns

```
19000
```

Example 2:

```
select (year(dateadd(month, 3, '2020-10-01 13:29:07.433')) - 2000) * 1000
```

Returns

```
21000
```

By adding 3 months to the current date, we are able to ensure that the 'next' year is selected instead of the current year when multiplying by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The number would appear to be:

```
select (year(dateadd(month, -10, getdate())) - 2017) * 1000 + 17000
```

Actually, I'm not sure if you want `+ 17000` or `+ 18000` but the idea is the same.  (Does the change on 2019-10-01 produce the 2020 number or the 2019 number?)

Comment: My current @LegacyKey is `19576`, so this value should be overrite for `20000` because its 1st of Octuber and LegacyKey starts with 19 instead 20, so returned @LegacyKey value should be  `20000`